# What's the best way to transform a string into an associative array

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

For the sake of exercise, I've written the few lines below in a bash script to transform a HTTP post input into an associative array. Following through on my learning, I was wondering, if there are different, maybe more elegant, ways to do this. I mean, I know there are different ways. I'm wondering which ones exist and what the advantages and disadvantages of each methods are.

Note: I'm using post as input here. The exercise however is to build a array from a multiple name/value pair string. The input could be coming from any files or other input source.

Note2: the string I'm dealing with could look like this: `name=myName&age=myAge`. So there are 2 delimiters. One separating name/value pairs (`&`) and the other separating the value from its name (`=`).

```
#!/bin/bash
read post;
declare -A myArr;
IFS_bck=$IFS;
IFS="=";
while read name value; do
  myArr[$name]=$value;
done < <(sed -rn -e 's/&/\n/g p' <<<"$post");
IFS=$IFS_bck;
```

P.S. I'm not willing to start a religious war. I'm simply wondering how you would do this and why you would chose your proposal over mine.

Comment: You want just one key-value pair in the array?

Comment: This isn't about Ubuntu - you'd be better asking on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @CarlH This is of course on-topic here..

Comment: Small question though, you said `multiple name/value pair string`. The example shows two pairs, but could this also be `name=myName&age=myAge&married=true` ? If that's the case, the you need something other than associative array. Likey a linked list would be better. And probably a different language - bash isn't the right tool for this

Comment: "… how you would do this and why you would chose …" The problem here is that you have given us [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/270345). You have already decided on an associative array as the solution, and are asking us how to build one. Depending on the actual problem, the rest of us might not even use an associative array at all. When it comes to records and fields, `awk` sweeps the floor with other tools, which is why kos picked that. If you're really into learning this, start with the actual problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this just using `bash` itself:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -e -p 'Enter the string: ' post
declare -A myArr

while IFS='&' read name age; do
    myArr["${name##*=}"]="${age##*=}"
done <<<"$post"

printf 'NAME: %s, AGE: %s\n' "${!myArr[@]}" "${myArr[@]}"
```

Here is what i get in the output:

```
Enter the string: name=Foo Bar&age=40
NAME: Foo Bar, AGE: 40
```

- The input string is spitted on `&` using `IFS` environmental variable
- The name and age values are parsed using parameter expansion pattern `${var##*=}`
- You can get all keys using `${!myArr[@]}` and all values using `${!myArr[@]}`

In practice, I don't think you would just make an associative array of one element. If you have multiple elements, replace the last `printf` line with a simple `for` construct to loop over the keys:

```
for key in "${!myArr[@]}"; do
    printf 'NAME: %s, AGE: %s\n' "$key" "${myArr["$key"]}"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

What you have doesn't look bad, but neither Bash nor `sed` play too well with splitting on multiple delimiters; personally I'd use AWK and simplify the script a bit (using AWK changing `IFS` becomes redundant; notice that you don't need semicolons at the end of statements in Bash):

```
#!/bin/bash
read post
declare -A myArr
while read name value; do
    myArr[$name]=$value
done < <(<<<"$post" awk -F= '{print $1,$2}' RS='&|\n')
```

The AWK command:

- Reads `$post`;
- Splits records on sequences of amperstands / newlines (splitting on newlines is a trick to prevent the `while` loop from failing on the final empty record);
- Splits fields on sequences of equal signs;
- Prints the fields separated by the default separator, a space.

```
% cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash
read post
declare -A myArr
while read name value; do
    myArr[$name]=$value
done < <(<<<"$post" awk -F= '{print $1,$2}' RS='&|\n')
printf '%s %s\n' "${myArr[name]}" "${myArr[age]}"
% bash script.sh 
name=myName&age=myAge
myName myAge
%
```

Comment: kossy, why not just `while IFS=\= ....` and get rid of unnecessary parsing and process substitution ..also OP should know that they should quote their variables..anyway, you have my +1 always..

Comment: @heemayl I remember seeing a comment here mentioning `read`'s `-d` option. How come neither of you have used it, and the comment's vanished?

Comment: @muru duh..need coffee..kos, go ahead..i am out..

Comment: @muru It was mine, but it's not viable since they're reading with `read`; if I use `&` as the delimiter I also force them to type `&` at the end.

Comment: (if they copy-paste. Otherwise I force them ro read a single key/value pair).

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way, using just `IFS`:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A myArr
IFS='&=' read -a post
for ((i = 0; i < ${#post[@]}; i += 2))
do
    myArr[${post[i]}]=${post[i + 1]}
done
for key in "${!myArr[@]}"
do
    printf "%s: %s\n" "$key" "${myArr[$key]}"
done
```

`read` splits the incoming line into words on *all* characters in `IFS`, so you can use both `&` and `=` in `IFS` to split on both. Given that the POST input always has a value for a key, this will work.

However, this method can't check if there's a strict alternation between `&` and `=`. So, for example, `age&myAge=name=myName` will be parsed so that `age=myAge` and `name=myName`.

---

#### A note about `IFS`

You have backed up `IFS` and restored it. But you only need `IFS` for `read`, so apply `IFS` only for `READ`:

```
IFS='...' read ... # or
while IFS='...' read ...; ...
```

Restoring `IFS` is tricky, since an unset `IFS` and an empty `IFS` affect the shell differently, but are the same when you take the value of `IFS` itself. That is:

```
IFS=
IFS_BAK="$IFS"
```

will give the same value for `IFS_BAK` as:

```
unset IFS
IFS_BAK="$IFS"
```

An empty `IFS` is exactly that: an empty string. However, an *unset* IFS causes the shell to behave as if the default `IFS` (space, tab, newline) was used:

```
$ foo='a  b  c'
$ printf "|%s|\n" $foo
|a|
|b|
|c|
$ IFS=; printf "|%s|\n" $foo
|a  b  c|
$ unset IFS; printf "|%s|\n" $foo
|a|
|b|
|c|
```

So, if you'd found yourself with an unset IFS, and then tried the old backup-and-restore-IFS trick, you might get surprising results. It's better to restrict changes to `IFS` to be only for those commands that need it.

Answer (score 1):

You have said:

> So there are 2 delimiters. One separating name/value pairs (&) and the other separating the value form its name (=).

Well, we can split name/value pairs using `&` as `IFS` into variables, and use suffix/prefix removal to free the actual name and age values.

```bsh
$> cat post-parse.sh                                                           
#!/bin/bash
IFS='&' read PAIR1 PAIR2
# if necessary use these as well
# name_key=${PAIR1%%=*}
# age_key=${PAIR2%%=*}
name_val=${PAIR1##*=}
age_val=${PAIR2##*=}
echo $name_val $age_val
$> ./post-parse.sh
name=Serg&age=25
Serg 25
$>
```

You've also said:

> The exercise however is to build a array from a multiple name/value pair string. The input could be coming from any files or other input source.

If we want to store multiple key-value pairs, we can read input line by line (so no need to use `sed` to get rid of `\n` there), and apply same concept I showed above:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A myArray
while read input_line ; # read input line by line
do
echo $input_line
  IFS='&' read PAIR1 PAIR2 <<< $input_line # split in two with &
  # name_key=${PAIR1%%=*}
  # age_key=${PAIR2%%=*}
  name_val=${PAIR1##*=}
  age_val=${PAIR2##*=}
  myArray[$name_val]=$age_val
done
# print out the array
for key in "${!myArray[@]}" 
do
   echo ${myArray[$key]} is $key
done
```

Sample run bellow uses here document but it could be anything, even a pipe. Point is, read command doesn't care where it gets input.

```
$> ./post-parse.sh << EOF                                                      
> name=John&age=25                                                             
> name=Jane&age=35                                                             
> EOF
name=John&age=25
name=Jane&age=35
25 is John
35 is Jane
```